# What is the name for the topology where every point is in the boundary of an open set?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there a name for topological spaces in which every point is in the boundary of an open set?

Comment: Observation: $X\setminus \{a\}$ is disconnected for all $a$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Did you overlook _in_? Every point of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is _in_ the boundary of an open set.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ is the plane with Euclidean topology and $a$ is a point then $X \backslash \{a\}$ is *path connected* for all $a$. Note that being path connected is stronger then being connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I did - probably thinking it would make the problem more interesting that ways ;)

Comment: New observation: $\overline a$ is not a connected component of $X$ for $a\in X$. So for Hausdorff spaces: There are no isolated points.

Comment: A refinement on @Hagen's new observation: A [$T_1$ space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) has this property if and only if it has no [isolated points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point).